# How to access the class of the child element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the class of the child element  to be "fa fa-minus-circle" when the user click on the header

```
<div class="case-study-header">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Case Study Header </div>
```

**Code**

```
 $('.case-study-header').click(function(){
           var state  = $('.case-study-header').children().attr('class');
           state.replace("fa fa-plus-circle", "fa fa-minus-circle");
            });
```

Comment: state.repalce : you maybe mean "replace" ?

Comment: Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/571ego8y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Change `repalce` to `replace`.
2. Change the whole logic to something simpler.

I guess you might need this:

```
$('.case-study-header').click(function(){
  var state  = $('.case-study-header').children().attr('class');
  state.replace("fa fa-plus-circle", "fa fa-minus-circle");
});
```

Instead of the above, use:

```
$('.case-study-header').click(function () {
    $('.case-study-header').children().attr('class', 'fa fa-minus-circle');         
});
```

Comment: You're reputation score is high enough for you to know that answering a duplicate question when you should be closing/deleting it doesn't look good.  I can't speak for the downvoter though, but to me it looks like fishing for points.  Same goes for everyone else answering when there's already a correct answer.

Comment: @mmmshuddup Fine. I agree with you. Will make sure to answer only the non-duplicate questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.case-study-header').click(function(){
     $('.case-study-header').children().attr('class', 'fa fa-minus-circle');         
  });
```

Set it again, it over-rides automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

```js
$('.case-study-header').click(function() {
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case-study-header">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Case Study Header
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggleClass method as below:

```
$('.case-study-header').click(function(){
       var state  = $('.case-study-header').children().toggleClass('class', 'fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');         
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: select all children having either `fa-plus-circle` or `fa-minus-circle` and toggle class.

```
$('.case-study-header').click(function(){
   var $children = $('.case-study-header').children('.fa-plus-circle, .fa-minus-circle');
   $children.toggleClass('class', 'fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');         
});
```